# How do I find out why connection with Mysql failed using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection

I have a node js and MySQL server running locally, and cannot find out why I am unable to connect. I am able to get the DB server running using the credentials, but all I get is the error message that was coded in and I would like to know if there is somewhere I can go to find out why it is not connecting successfully. I'm thinking it's either a syntax error (Hoping this isn't it I've been looking the file up and down) or maybe a permissions issue but just want to know how I can look into this further.

Thanks

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user:'admin',
password: 'root',
database: 'world'

});   

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{

if(err)
    console.log('This sucks :( try something else ');
else
    console.log('DB connection actually worked :)');


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
    console.log('This sucks :( try something else ');
```

to

```
    console.log('This sucks :( try something else ' + err.stack);
```

and you should see some diagnostic messages to describe your failure.

Answer (score 0):

you can `console.log(err)`directly

```
if(err)
{
    console.log('This sucks :( try something else ');
    console.log(err);
}
```